# How to send email to all members of a Facebook group

Tags: facebook-groups

Is there any way to send an email to every member of a group in Facebook given that I'm the admin of that group? Or just send a message to every member of that group and they will see it on their Facebook inbox?

If this is not possible may I know if there is a way to get all the Facebook email addresses of members in a group so that I can just use the usual messaging system in Facebook to send a message to each of those emails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Instructions](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=224898750855930#How-do-I-send-a-message-to-everyone-in-my-group?) from Facebook on how to send messages to entire group.

> **How do I send a message to everyone in my group?**
>
> Any group member or admin can make posts in a group using the options at the top of the group. When a post is made, members are notified on Facebook and by email, and they can respond with comments. Members can change their notification settings, but they will always see new posts when they visit the group.
>
> Group admins can’t send private messages to all members of a group. The best way to reach all members at once and start a discussion is to make a post in the group.

If this doesn't solve the problem go to Solution 2

**Solution 2**

This is going to require a little coding and some Facebook Open Graph knowledge.

1. You must be logged into facebook :)
2. First you will need to query all the members of your group. Here is an example query

   ```
   api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+gid%2C+uid+from+group_member+where+gid+%3D+146797922030397+limit+50&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAJDmxL89UqxXbZAqR4PwcIIE8nj74hiPi618zMJLuzJh1otaVC2XIxjmA78yzsxZC9pDcBZBaAW4He2ZCh1sVsYAbahvXwZDZD&format=json
   ```

   This only works on groups you are a member of. Also my example link is set to take the first 50. If you need more adjust the Url query accordingly. The important number in this is the gid. Your gid can be found in the url of the group page.
3. Now you have all the uid (user ids)
4. These uid's can be used to get their user account names Example:
   Here is Brad's

   ```
   graph.facebook.com/220439
   ```
5. Take the account names and append `@facebook.com`
6. Create a csv with all the email addresses copy this line into Facebook messenger.

You would want to automate this in a script, as manually looking up each individual user name would be tedious.